# How unique was the ban of cousin marriage by the Catholic church?

Tags: catholic-church

How extreme was the ban of cousin marriage by the Catholic church compared to other countries? Did they manage to effectively enforce their ban of consanguinity up to 7 degrees in a way that's unique compared to other cultures?

Comment: You should tell if you are interested in some specific place or period. And the first step is to differentiate between absolute impediments (e.g. brother-sister) and impediments subject to dispensations (e.g. cousins). A dispensation could be easy to get, or not, depending on where/when. It may be just a way to filter out obvious abuses, or to discourage inbred families. In Brazil's XIX century there were a number of cousin marriages, subject to not hard to get dispensations, in both real biographies and fictional literature.

Comment: If you look at the ancestors of *His Most Catholic Majesty* [Charles II of Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_II_of_Spain#Ancestry), the answer might suggest that the Catholic prohibition was not very effective.

Comment: [Please document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/1401)

Comment: For considerably more than 30 pieces of silver, anything was possible in the church.

Comment: You asked one question in the title, and two different questions in the question body. Which one is your question?